# Cluster install with `kubeadm` on Ubuntu. Failing on `kubeadm init` with `getsockopt: connection refused`

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm running Ubuntu 16.0.4.

I am in the process of starting a Kubernetes cluster using `kubeadm`.

I am currently initializing the master node with `kubeadm init`.

I get the following error:

`[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhos
t:10255/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.`

I have swap turned off, and I installed docker with `apt-get install docker.io` after removing a previous installation of `docker-ce` with `apt-get remove docker-ce && apt-get autoremove --purge docker-ce`.

I am aware some people have had problems if they ever even installed `docker-ce` and they've started with fresh environments (See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55281).  I really want to avoid having to do that.

How can I get beyond this error?

Thanks.

---

Update. Running `journalctl -u kubelet -f` yielded:

`error: failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: "cgroupfs" is different from docker cgroup driver: "systemd"`

This led me to believe I needed

```
cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"]
}
EOF
```

I restarted `docker` with `systemctl restart docker`

And then retried with `kubeadm reset && kubeadm init`

That worked and solved my problem.

I would like to point out that the `kubeadm` instructions seem to tell you currently to do something completely different.

They tell you to do:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
EOF
```

That just led me down the wrong path.

I didn't see the note after that:

`Or ensure the --cgroup-driver kubelet flag is set to the same value as Docker (e.g. cgroupfs).`

Thanks!

`

Comment: you need to dig into the parts. Checkout with `journalctl -u kubelet -f` the last logs of the kubelet. list with `docker ps` all running containers and look at the logs of apiserver, controller manager, and scheduler for detailed error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system needed

```
cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"]
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error i think you should definitely see the logs as suggested by @David. Now your setup is unable to hit kubelet which runs on 127.0.0.1:10255.Here port 10255 suggests that.

So i think your kubelet is not properly installed or configured. I would suggest you to restart kubelet by hitting command "service kubelet restart" and then running "kubeadm reset" to clean the corrupted setup and finally "kubeadm init". 
    One more point i want add here though it's not related to your question but you should add "--pod-network-cidr=" with kubeadm init. As many network plugins ask for this.

Comment: How do I know what to provide for the cidr?

Comment: You can select any network plugins from the list given in this link.( https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network ).Select the plugins and there you find the argument which you have to pass in --pod-network-cidr= <> .

Comment: Thanks I selected flannel and used the appropriate CIDR

Answer (score 0):

I have updated following config on all nodes and restarted docker and kubelet -

```
    cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
    {
      "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"]
    }
    EOF
```

restart

```
    sudo systemctl restart docker
    sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```